# how to read images directly from amazon s3 bucket to google -colaboratory without downloading the images in google-colaboratory

Tags: amazon-s3, google-colaboratory

i want to read the images directly from the amazon s3 bucket without downloading the images

i tried one method get method but it download the images

```
import boto
from boto.s3.key import Key
keyId ="your_aws_key_id"
sKeyId="your_aws_secret_key_id"
srcFileName="abc.txt"
destFileName="s3_abc.txt"
bucketName="mybucket001"
conn = boto.connect_s3(keyId,sKeyId)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucketName)
#Get the Key object of the given key, in the bucket
k = Key(bucket,srcFileName)
#Get the contents of the key into a file 
k.get_contents_to_filename(destFileName)
```